# Rails where on query result

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model- `Link` - that has many hits. What I'm trying to do is aggregate data on hits per hour over time from a database table - `hits` - with columns `year`, `month`, `day`, and `hour`.

Everything is working fine, but when I run the code below, I end up with almost **1,000 queries on the database**, which seems quite excessive.

```
#before iteration
@hits = @link.hits.group('year, month, day, hour')
  .order('year ASC, month ASC, day ASC, hour ASC')
  .select('year, month, day, hour, count(*) as hits')


#inside iteration

#Line breaks are included here for easy reading
hits_per_hour =
  @hits.where(
    :year => t.year, 
    :month => t.month,
    :day => t.day,
    :hour => t.hour
  ).map(&:hits).first || 0
```

Here `t` is a `Time` object that iterates in steps of 1 hour since the first hit a link received.

I would think that rails would store the query result instead of re-querying every time. I also haven't been able to find anything about caching the query results or anything. Am I just missing something completely, or is this really the easiest way?

Here is a sample of what the queries look like (this is what I see in my logs in blocks of a thousand):

```
SELECT year, month, day, hour, count(*) as hits
FROM `hits`
WHERE
  `hits`.`link_id` = 1 AND
  `hits`.`year` = 2012 AND
  `hits`.`month` = 11 AND
  `hits`.`day` = 2 AND
  `hits`.`hour` = 14
GROUP BY year, month, day, hour
ORDER BY year ASC, month ASC, day ASC, hour ASC
```

Comment: what are the 1000 queries asking for? Could this be improved by eager-loading associations?

Comment: There are no associations being loaded. It just has to run every hour since a link was created (about 3 weeks right now). I'll add a sample of one of the queries to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. So `@hits` is going to be an ActiveRecord::Relation object - a SQL query, essentially. I believe that because each iteration calls `.where` on it with different parameters, and thus alters the query, Rails has decided it has to rerun the query for each hour.

The simplest fix is probably to 'collapse' the Relation into an array before iterating, and then use pure Ruby to select the results you want each time:

```
@hits = @link.hits.group('year, month, day, hour')
  .order('year ASC, month ASC, day ASC, hour ASC')
  .select('year, month, day, hour, count(*) as hits').all
```

and then:

```
hits_per_hour = (@hits.select{|record| record.year == t.year && record.month == t.month && record.day == t.day && record.hour == t.hour}.map(&:hits).first || 0)
```

I don't think this is actually likely to be the best solution, though. Depending on exactly what data you need and what you're doing with it, you should be able to get everything done in the database.

Comment: I knew I was missing something. Thank you. Like you said, this might not be the *best* solution, so I'll wait to accept the answer. If there isn't a better one by the end of the day you are definitely getting it.

Comment: @Jon Thanks. I'd take a shot at the 'better' solution myself, but I distinctly remember that grouping is one of the places where mysql is least like postgres (where my database expertise lies).

Comment: My answer would be the same. And if there is any better solution it depends on how many times you expect to make those queries. I mean, how would cache get more hits?